# Autowiring a repository inside a MappedSuperClass

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design

I am unable to `@Autowire` a repository inside `@MappedSuperClass`

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class HomeAddressType {

 private AddressTypeRespository addressTypeRepository;

 @Embedded
 protected AddressTypeId addressTypeId;

 @Autowired
 AddressTypeRespository(AddressTypeRespository addressTypeRespository) {
   this.addressTypeRepository=addressTypeRepository;
   this.addressTypeId = new AddressTypeId(this.addressTypeRepository.getAddressTypeByCode().getId);
 }   

}
```

So that I can hide this in my domain model object `HomeAddress` because I am using hibernate annotations and `HomeAddress` is actually an `Address` with `AddressTypeId(FK)` to `AddressType` table

So when my `Aggregate Factory` builds `HomeAddress` it has a hidden `AddressType` by default. So I can hide this from domain model consumers.

```
class HomeAddress extends HomeAddressType{
      @Embedded
      AddressId addressId;
      ......
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific to the needs ?

Comment: You cant autowire because @MappedSuperClass (Jpa entity) is not a Spring bean. I cannot suggest the right way as the question is totally unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot autowire beans in a `MappedSuperClass` since it is not managed by spring.

One workaround I can suggest would be to have a static field of type `AddressTypeRespository` in one of your managed bean that you initialize at startup (in a constructor for instance), then you can access this field from your `HomeAddressType`